# Survey vs. Questionnaire?

Tags: meaning, terminology

What is the difference between a survey and a questionnaire? Which word would be more appropriate in a report?

Answer (score 2):

A *questionaire* is an instrument for collecting data, and almost always involve asking a given subject to respond to a set of oral or writen quesitons.

A *survey* is a process for gathering data that could involve a wide variety of data collection methods, including a questionaire. It also could involve observing or measuring things that go beyond questions, including physical measurements, judgments by a researcher, analyses of other existing data.

In a report, the correct term depends on what was done. Questionaire would only be approrpiate if the study was done using a process that was primarily based on written or oral question.

Answer (score 0):

A 'survey' is a much wider term than 'questionnaire'.

A 'survey' is defined by Oxford Dictionaries as 'a general view, examination, or description of someone or something'.

In order to conduct an examination, a number of techniques may be used, from observation, research, sounding of opinion etc. When researching opinion, one method is to ask contributors to complete a 'questionnaire'.

A 'questionnaire' is a list of questions, devised to extract all the relevant information, and is given to people to complete. The resultant answers are then analysed.